# Summation Sign Division

Tags: calculus, functions

I hope I can be precise enough. As my name already suggests mathematics currently is not one of my strengths. My question is:

How do I solve the following equation:

$$
\sum_{4}^{10}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k-1}\right)
$$

What I do not understand in particular is how I am supposed to get rid of the "1/" in the first part of the equation. I hope I made my point clear.

With kind regards
Math Noob

Comment: Welcome to MSE! The notation is a bit ambiguous, can you maybe upload a photo? I'll edit your question so people can know how to help you. Also please consider using MathJax.

Comment: You sum is a [telescoping sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series), if you expand out the expression, there are a lot of cancellation between consecutive terms.

Comment: Is my edit similar to the input you had?

Comment: the edit is perfect thank you so much, next time i will put more effort into it.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=\color{green}{4}}^{\color{red}{10}}(\frac 1k-\frac{1}{k-1})=$$

$$(\frac{1}{\color{green}{4}}-\frac{1}{\color{green}{4}-1}) +$$
$$(\frac 15 -\frac{1}{5-1}) +$$
$$(\frac 16 -\frac{1}{6-1}) +$$
$$(\frac 17-\frac{1}{7-1}) +$$
$$(\frac 18 -\frac{1}{8-1}) +$$
$$(\frac 19 -\frac{1}{9-1}) +$$
$$(\frac{1}{\color{red}{10}}-\frac{1}{\color{red}{10}-1}) =$$

$$\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{3}=  ?$$
This is what we call "Telescoping".
In general

$$\sum_{k=a}^b(\frac 1k -\frac{1}{k-1})=\frac 1b-\frac{1}{a-1}=\frac{a-1-b}{b(a-1)}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. But isn`t there a possibilty to put the "1/" somewhere behind the summation sign?

Comment: @MathNoob No. take an example and check.

Comment: Okay thanks. So this is the "shortest way" to calculate the equation? If n was not 10 but 100 wouldn`t it take very long to calculate the equation?

Comment: @MathNoob: Which terms would cancel if $n$ were 100? Which would be left behind?

Comment: I am trying to use the following formula: 

n
∑  k=n/2(n+1) 
k=1

I can not do that however if the "1/" is standing in my way at the very beginning of the equation.

Comment: @MathNoob Look now, i added some lines in the end.

Comment: Yes that was what i meant. Does your formula have a name so I can look it up somewhere and find further information on it?

Comment: @MathNoob That is telescoping technique for computing some special sums.